# How binding combobox listbox?

Tags: xaml

There is an empty ComboBox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TClUm.png)
When I click on "Open 1", a window pops up with a LisBox in which I can add/delete entries after I
but they are not saved in the ComboBox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzZTk.png)

it's code with ComboBox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbFarm"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="211,50,211,267">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontSize="13" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

it's code with ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="usersList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ButtonBase.Click="Edit_Click" Margin="0,0,50,0" 
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontSize="13" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

my class

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string? name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }

       
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set
            {
                age = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Age");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext();
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.ElementName = "usersList";
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Text"); 
            cmbFarm.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, binding); 
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();
        // загружаем данные из БД
        db.Users.Load();
        // и устанавливаем данные в качестве контекста
        DataContext = db.Users.Local.ToObservableCollection();

    }
    // Open
    private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Open Open = new Open(new User());
        if (Open.ShowDialog() == true)
        {

            User user= (User)this.Resources["cmbFarm"];
            user.Name = user.Name; 

            User User = Open.User;
            db.Users.Add(User);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    } 
}
```

window with lisbox

```
public partial class Open : Window
{
    public User User { get; private set; }

    ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext();
    public Open(User user)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += Open_Loaded;
        User = user;
        DataContext = User;
    }

    // Loaded
    private void Open_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();
        
        db.Users.Load();
        DataContext = db.Users.Local.ToObservableCollection();            
    }
    // Add
    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        UserWindow UserWindow = new UserWindow(new User());
        if (UserWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            User User = UserWindow.User;
            db.Users.Add(User);
            db.SaveChanges();

            
        }
    }

    // Delete
    private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        User? user = usersList.SelectedItem as User;
        if (user is null) return;
        db.Users.Remove(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        
    }
}
```

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=helloapp.db");

        }

    }
```

tried to use the INotifyPropertyChanged